# $1$D bidirectional random walk question

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

> In a $1$D random walk on x axis a
>   particle can turn left with
>   probability $\frac{3}{4}$ and right
>   with probability $\frac{1}{4}$. What
>   is the probability that $|x|\leq 1 $
>   for $1\leq t\leq 4$ total steps.

I am not looking for answers, but ways to think about it. How to approach this kind of a question? What is a good source that discusses random walks from the basics.

Comment: I assume you are starting at the origin.  Draw a tree diagram.  With such a small range of values of $t$, you can calculate all the relevant probabilities with not much effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user6312's suggestion to use a tree diagram is good, but I'm a bit
lazy and prefer to do the calculations using linear algebra. 
Matrix multiplication automatically adds up the contributions from the branches of the tree diagram.

You start the particle at some state in the set $A=\{ -1, 0, 1\}$. Let $Q$ be the 
matrix of transition probabilities from this set into itself, i.e., 
$$ Q=\pmatrix{0&1/4&0\cr 3/4&0&1/4\cr 0&3/4&0}.$$

Then $Q_{ij}^n$, the $(i,j)$th entry in the $n$th power of $Q$, is 
the probability that the walk is in state $j$ at time $n$, starting 
at state $i$, *without leaving* the set $A$.

Since you don't want the answer, I will simply say that
the row sums of $Q^4$ give you what you want, each row sum
corresponding to one of the three possible initial states.